# Pandas: convert all column from string to number except two?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose we have

`>>> df.dtype
Name        object
Height      object
Weight      object
Age         object
Job         object`

Is there any simple way to covert all columns except Name and Job columns with .to_numeric() method?

I have tried but it doesn't work

`df.iloc[df.columns != Name & df.columns != Job] = pd.to_numeric(df.iloc[df.columns != Name & df.columns != Job], errors='coerce')`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The simplest way that comes to my mind would be to make a list of all the columns except Name and Job and then iterate `pandas.to_numeric` over them:

```
cols=[i for i in df.columns if i not in ["Name","Job"]]
for col in cols:
    df[col]=pd.to_numeric(df[col])
```

Edit:

If you absolutely want to use numbers instead of columns names and already know at which indice they are:

```
for i in [i for i in list(range(len(df.columns))) if i not in [0,4]]:
    df.iloc[:,i]=pandas.to_numeric(df.iloc[:,i])
```

That's more complicated than necessary though.

Comment: Thank you, so simple. But what if I want to use index, then what should I write?

Comment: What do you mean with "use index" ? The operation is propagated on all the rows, so you don't need to bother with the index.

Comment: instead of using ["Name","Job"] in  `cols=[i for i in df.columns if i not in ["Name","Job"]]`. Is it possible to use column index like this `[ df.loc[:, 0], df.loc[:, 4] ]`

Comment: Thank you, that is quite useful in some cases

Comment: can this be done somehow inplace? or with a list comprehension but then for several column? because the assignment inside the list comprehension is not allowed

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have DF:

```
df
Out[125]: 
  Name Height Weight Age Job
0    0      2      3   4   5

df.dtypes
Out[126]: 

Name      object
Height    object
Weight    object
Age       object
Job       object
dtype: object
```

If you have to use pd.to_numeric to convert those columns, you can do it this way:

```
df2 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([pd.to_numeric(df[e],errors='coerce') \
                               for e in df.columns if e not in ['Name','Job']]).T,\
                 df[['Name','Job']]],axis=1)


df2
Out[138]: 
   Height  Weight  Age Name Job
0       2       3    4    0   5

df2.dtypes
Out[139]: 
Height     int64
Weight     int64
Age        int64
Name      object
Job       object
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to use index? Also, if I understand you correctly, there is other way to do it ?